# R function to process multiple expressions

Tags: r, function, parsing, expression

I'm trying to create a function that can evaluate multiple independent expressions. My goal is to input many expressions at once like `myfunction(x = 2, y = c(5,10,11) , z = 10, ...)`, and use each expression's name and value to feed other functions inside of it. The `transform()` function works kind of like that: `transform(someData, x = x*2, y = y + 1)`.

I know I can get the name and the value of an expression using:

```
> names(expression(x=2))
[1] "x"
> eval(expression(x=2))
[1] 2
```

However, I don't know how to pass those expressions through a function. Here is some of my work so far.

With unquoted expression (x=2) I could not pass it using the dots (...).

```
> myfunction <- function(...) { names(expression(...)) }
> myfunction(x=2)
expression(...)
```

Now, using quotes. It gets the value **but not the name**. Parse structure is different from the tradicional expression. See `class(expression(x=2))` and `class(parse(text="x=2"))`, then `str(expression(x=2))` and `str(parse(text="x=2"))`.

```
> myfunction <- function(...) {
assign("temp",...)
results <- parse(text=temp)
cat(names(results))
cat(eval(results))
}
> myfunction("x=2") 
> 2
```

So, any ideas?

Comment: If you ever have a function that does what you want, you can view the inside of it by looking at first 'methods' then 'getAnywhere'. For example: methods(transform); getAnywhere(transform.zoo). Here you can see the line e<-eval... where I believe it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use fix(transform) instead of fix(transform.data.frame) to look inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you want the return of your function to be. You can get the names and expressions passed to a function using

```
myfunction <- function(...) {
    x<-substitute(...())
    #names(x)
    x
}
myfunction(x = 2, y = c(5,10,11) , z = 10)
```

Here you get a named list and each of the items is an unevaluated expression or language object that you can evaluate later if you like.